# JS executes fine in vscode but doesn't execute in github, instead receive "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Tags: javascript, html, performance

I've been trying to integrate PartyTown, a framework that will use web workers to execute Javascripts instead of the main thread, and while PartyTown works perfectly fine in the live-server hosted in VScode, it doesn't run as expected in GitHub when trying to test if the project works well in phones.

This is the code, alongside the JS scripts I want to load:

```
<!--  PartyTown (used to relieve the main thread from the javascript executions)  -->
<script src="~partytown/partytown.js"></script>
<!--  PartyTown (used to relieve the main thread from the javascript executions)  -->

<!--  General Functions  -->
<script defer type="text/partytown" src="../javascript/app.js"></script>
<!--  General Functions  -->

<!--  Install Cookies JavaScript Library  -->
<script type="text/partytown" rel="preload" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.5/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<!--  Install Cookies JavaScript Library  -->

<!--  Redirect to Correct Language Versions JavaScript  -->
<script type="text/partytown" eager src="../javascript/multilanguage-serve.js"></script>
<!--  Redirect to Correct Language Versions JavaScript  -->

<!--  Font Awesome Library  -->
<script type="text/partytown" defer src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/82a93eb8fe.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- - Font Awesome Library  -->
```

I am confident the files are present in GitHub, since when I edit the html from the inspect element tab and remove the PartyTown script together with the type="text/partytown" attribute, the scripts run as expected

Comment: Do you have a folder `~partytown` in github?

Comment: @Barmar yes I do

Comment: Which file is getting the 404 error? DevTools should show you the full URL being requested, you should be able to compare that with the actual file layout.

Comment: @Barmar I am not getting any full urls, I'm just receiving that one singular message on the title, being "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()"

Comment: If you go to the Network tab of DevTools you should be able to find the full URLs.

Comment: @Barmar I took your concern and started to reexamine the problem again, and the reason it wasn't working on github is because it tried to find the partytown folder at the root of the entire directory, going outside the repository's directory, meaning i had no control. I changed a couple of lines in the PartyTown scripts to start looking at a desired directory where I could fix the problem and did it. Thank you for the help and the idea

Answer (score -1):

Go to the network tab of DevTools and check where the http request is looking for the script. Try and find a solution around that problem. What I did is that I changed the `partytown.js` and which directories it looks for to find the required library files it needs. I pointed its search to my desired folder, and the script worked fine. Hope this helps

Comment: I suspect github doesn't support the `~username` shortcut in URLs.